# Special characters in Xcode look different in edit and view modes

Tags: ios, xcode, special-characters

I want to use a special character on an iOS button. When I insert it from special characters collection located in Edit/Special Characters menu it looks like this:

[image]

But after I exit the edit mode or run the app on device the character turns into this:

[image]

It looks like it uses different font. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the character viewer (you may need to enable this in the Settings / Language)

You can inspect the arrows in here, and then check the font variations.

[image: Lucida Grande Bold Left Arrow]

Once you've located the font you want, apply that to the label. I suspect you want Lucida Grande Bold.